Updating ca certificates manually
On an Ubuntu-Server Distro
I want to install new ca certificates using ansible therefore I've looked into deploying the ca-certificate manually in contrast to using dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates.

I copy the .crt in /usr/share/ca-certificates/domain/ where all the others are stored.
I create a symlink from /etc/ssl/certs/ to said .crt
I write domain/.crt in /etc/ca-certificates.conf
I update-ca-certificates

Afterwards I see the certificate is sucessfully added in the /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt file. But when I try to verify it using
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect domaincontroller

I get "Unable to get local issuer certificate"
If I then manually type
dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates

and unselect and then reselect it works.
Does anyone know what I am missing?

I was using the wrong directory, under ubuntu you can add the .crt directly to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates, and they are automatically trusted.
Just had to update-ca-certificates and it worked like a charm.
